# Firebreath Plugin to draw image on the browser

Tags: macos, cocoa, firebreath

Im developing a plugin that implements a ImageViewer application using FireBreath in MAC OSX, the image is located in the local filesystem. I have the following code snippet:
help me in implementing the **getDrawingPrimitive** function.

```
 `FB::PluginWindowMac *wnd = dynamic_cast<FB::PluginWindowMac*>(win);
 wnd->getDrawingPrimitive();
 /* code related to openGL*/
 CALayer* layer = [CALayer new];
 [layer setContents:(id)[ImageHandler setImageWithURL:@"somePath.jpg"]];`
```

setContents receives the argument of type (CGImageRef).
Is this the right way to set the image to a CALayer object?

Comment: Could you specify the problem please.

Comment: BasicMediaPlayer is actually only a drawing example using OpenGL.  This is not a question; this is a complaint.  That's not real helpful here. Break the problem down to what you actually don't know how to do and ask that.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific in my question, I have edited it accordingly. @taxilian any ideas would be of a lot help.

Answer (score 0):

On calling **wnd->StartAutoInvalidate(sometimelapse);** It makes a call to **onDraw** function depending on Drawing Model and Event Model selected. The window context of type **CGContextRef** is obtained. This context can be used further to draw whatever is required. In order to draw an image, the image is converted to CGImageRef and using **CGContextDrawImage** the image is drawn on to the context.